# Можно ли сократить?

Tags: python

Я написал код, который открывает текстовые файлы (типа, вводишь название текстового файла и он открывается). Можно ли его как-нибудь укоротить или что-то поменять, чтобы он выглядел более компактнее?

```
import os

filename = input() 

class textual():
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if name == filename + '.doc':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.docx':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.pdf':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.html':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.txt':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.rtf':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.odt':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.djvu':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.mobi':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.epub':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
        elif name == filename + '.fb2':
            os.startfile(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог (галочка около ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отделяем расширение и смотрим, есть ли оно среди нужных:

```
extensions = {".doc", ".pdf", итд}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\", topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if ext in extensions:
           os.startfile(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Тогда уж множество а не список

Comment: @Flyme да, пожалуй.